# Why isn't it GARBAGE COLLECTED

Tags: java

Look at the following line of code

```
myClass.myMethod(new MyObject());
```

here i am passing a anonymous object in the argument , so this object does not have a reference hence should be eligible for garbage collection **( i am not sure)** , but is there any chance that this object may get garbage collected before getting assigned to the parameter of `myMethod(MyObject obj)`, might be just in case when this object is created and context immediately switched to some other thread and when context returned to thread which created that object the object is not there.

like

```
thread1 |
        |
        | myClass.myMethod(new MyObject()); <- called, and immediately 
                                                 thread2|
                                                        |
                                                        |
                                                        |  // doing some work
          meanwhile GC sees new MyObject(); and eats it
 thread1| //gets chance again 
        |
        | myClass.myMethod(null); object gone
```

May be look like a silly question , it never happened to me ,  but i was just curious.

If you answer please explain

thanks

Comment: It has a reference on the stack immediately the `new` opcode completes.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection kicks into place only if the object you have is eligible for GC. You would want GC if are dealing with one (or more) of the following scenarios:

1. Nullifying your reference variable
2. Re-assigning your reference variable
3. Island of Isolation
4. Object created inside method

The code snippet you provided seems to be the third case. You are instantiating `MyObject()` inside `myMethod()`. So when `myMethod()` is called, it goes inside the **stack frame.** If your method is popped out (by dereferencing), `myObject` becomes unreachable and becomes eligible for Garbage Collection

```
class Test 
{ 

    // to store object name 
    String obj_name; 

    public Test(String obj_name) 
    { 
        this.obj_name = obj_name; 
    } 

    static void myMethod1(Test t) 
    { 
        //object t1 inside method becomes unreachable when myMethod1(...) removed 
        myMethod2(new Test("t2")); 

    } 
    static void myMethod2(Test t) 
    { 
        // dereference myMethod2(...)
        return;
    } 

    // Driver method 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        myMethod1(new Test("t1")); 

        // calling garbage collector 
        System.gc(); 
    } 

    @Override
    // Overriding finalize method to check which object is garbage collected
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable 
    { 
        // will print name of object 
        System.out.println(this.obj_name + " successfully garbage collected!"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: new Test("t1") needs to be into t what if another thread kicks in before that happenns, and as new Test("t1) is created , so can garbage collected see it as eligible

Comment: Short answer is that when GC kicks in, JVM blocks all running threads. Read this [blog](https://www.cubrid.org/blog/understanding-java-garbage-collection) for more details.

Comment: Your assumption about `myObject` becoming null depends on the use-case. Ask yourself, how would it become null. Are you explicitly de-referencing it or do you have circualar island of isolation?

Comment: GC does not block all running threads. It runs concurrently. Java garbage collectors haven't 'stopped the world' for over 20 years. He is not instantiating it inside the method. He is instantiating it before the method is invoked. 'If your method is popped out (by dereferencing)' is meaningless.